# failed job to create docker image

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins

when i run the the dockerfile on the server directly its working perfect and build the image but when i run it from jenkins it give me this error

```
    Step 5/67 : RUN pecl install xdebug-3.0.4 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
 ---> Running in 111bf1524f04
downloading xdebug-3.0.4.tgz ...
Starting to download xdebug-3.0.4.tgz (215,870 bytes)
.............................................done: 215,870 bytes
87 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-defaultuser2CL8YH/xdebug-3.0.4
running: /tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config
ls: cannot access '.': Operation not permitted
configure: error: working directory cannot be determined
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/xdebug/configure --with-php-config=/usr/local/bin/php-config' failed
The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug-3.0.4 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

any ideas what is the problem
i run this step as root and still same problem

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same error yesterday. Have you tried using another image, e.g. php:7.4-fpm-buster (or cli)? I noticed that the images have been updated two days ago. Changing the image did the trick for me.

Comment: faced this issue on gitlabCI with `php:7.3.31-apache` and  `php:7.4.24-apache` images. issue was gone when I changed to `php:7.4-fpm-buster`

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into your error [too](https://github.com/department-of-veterans-affairs/va.gov-cms/issues/6216) with various different commands. This appears to be a change introduced to the upstream dependency Moby which goes into Alpine Linux which goes into the PHP image.

Two solutions:

Short term: Pin your image to a previous version, e.g. php:7.3.28-apache (7.3.29 is broken on Docker 19 for me).

Long term: Upgrade Docker to 20.10.0+ AND libseccomp 2.4.4+ AND runc 1.0.0-rc93+ (read [Alpine 3.14.0 release notes](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.14.0).

Sources:
https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/1177
https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/41353
https://github.com/moby/moby/commit/a18139111d8a203bd211b0861c281ebe77daccd9
https://github.com/alpinelinux/docker-alpine/issues/182
https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.14.0

Answer (score 1):

i removed docker and installed newer version and problem solved

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue.
I could not build docker images based php7.4-fpm on docker in  gitlab.
It resolved via updating docker engine to 20 from 19.